# when start the mongos for sharding Getting error

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Quickly I giving the details, I have 4 Linux VMs with MongoDB installation. 1. Mongodb is for config so in Mongod.conf file enabled replication with shading like below

replication:
replSetName: "config"

sharding:
clusterRole: configsvr

and also initiated replication and it's a primary similar did for 2 vm for 2 nodes of shading then

1 separate VM there so I stopped the Mongod and try to start the Mongos but getting an error so please find the long error message and it not stop i pressed control+c and stopped

````
and added 27017 MongoDB default port in all nodes firewall** ```

Please find the below error:

```**mangos --configdb config/IP_address:27017**```



2023-11-05T11:15:24.562+0530 W  SHARDING [main] Running a sharded cluster with fewer than 3 config servers should only be done for testing purposes and is not recommended for production.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.595+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2023-11-05T11:15:24.598+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  SHARDING [mongosMain] mongos version v4.2.24
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] db version v4.2.24
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] git version: 5e4ec1d24431fcdd28b579a024c5c801b8cde4e2
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] modules: none
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] build environment:
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     distmod: rhel70
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     distarch: x86_64
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     target_arch: x86_64
2023-11-05T11:15:24.615+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] options: { sharding: { configDB: "config/172.25.122.151:27017" } }
2023-11-05T11:15:24.618+0530 I  NETWORK  [mongosMain] Starting new replica set monitor for config/172.25.122.151:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:24.637+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 172.25.122.151:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:24.638+0530 I  SHARDING [thread1] creating distributed lock ping thread for process localhost.localdomain:27017:1699163124:-4073906567926768333 (sleeping for 30000ms)
2023-11-05T11:15:24.694+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for config is config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:24.694+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:24.694+0530 I  SHARDING [Sharding-Fixed-0] Updating sharding state with confirmed set config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:24.694+0530 I  SHARDING [Sharding-Fixed-0] Updating ShardRegistry connection string for shard config from: config/172.25.122.151:27017 to: config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:25.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:25.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:25.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:25.618+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:26.118+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:26.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:26.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:26.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:26.618+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:27.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:27.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 5 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:27.618+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:27.619+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:27.619+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 6 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:28.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:28.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 7 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:28.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:28.618+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 8 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:28.694+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:29.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:29.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 9 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:29.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:29.618+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 10 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:30.118+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:30.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:30.118+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 11 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:15:30.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:31.118+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:15:31.618+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:15:31.618+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
^C2023-11-05T11:15:31.704+0530 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2023-11-05T11:15:31.704+0530 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close all sockets...
2023-11-05T11:15:31.705+0530 I  ASIO     [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:15:31.705+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Dropping all pooled connections to 172.25.122.151:27017 due to ShutdownInProgress: Shutting down the connection pool
2023-11-05T11:15:31.706+0530 W  SHARDING [mongosMain] Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: interrupted at shutdown
2023-11-05T11:15:31.707+0530 I  SHARDING [shard-registry-reload] Periodic reload of shard registry failed  :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: could not get updated shard list from config server :: caused by :: interrupted at shutdown; will retry after 30s
2023-11-05T11:15:31.707+0530 W  SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: interrupted at shutdown
2023-11-05T11:15:31.707+0530 I  ASIO     [ShardRegistry] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:15:31.707+0530 I  ASIO     [TaskExecutorPool-0] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:15:31.708+0530 W  SHARDING [signalProcessingThread] error encountered while cleaning up distributed ping entry for localhost.localdomain:27017:1699163124:-4073906567926768333 :: caused by :: ShutdownInProgress: Server is shutting down
2023-11-05T11:15:31.708+0530 W  SHARDING [shard-registry-reload] cant reload ShardRegistry  :: caused by :: CallbackCanceled: Callback canceled
2023-11-05T11:15:31.708+0530 I  ASIO     [shard-registry-reload] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:15:31.708+0530 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
[geopits@localhost ~]$ mongos --configdb config/172.25.122.151:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.645+0530 W  SHARDING [main] Running a sharded cluster with fewer than 3 config servers should only be done for testing purposes and is not recommended for production.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.648+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2023-11-05T11:26:40.676+0530 I  CONTROL  [main]
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  SHARDING [mongosMain] mongos version v4.2.24
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] db version v4.2.24
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] git version: 5e4ec1d24431fcdd28b579a024c5c801b8cde4e2
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] modules: none
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] build environment:
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     distmod: rhel70
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     distarch: x86_64
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain]     target_arch: x86_64
2023-11-05T11:26:40.688+0530 I  CONTROL  [mongosMain] options: { sharding: { configDB: "config/172.25.122.151:27017" } }
2023-11-05T11:26:40.690+0530 I  NETWORK  [mongosMain] Starting new replica set monitor for config/172.25.122.151:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.702+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 172.25.122.151:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.703+0530 I  SHARDING [thread1] creating distributed lock ping thread for process localhost.localdomain:27017:1699163800:3189634207339164914 (sleeping for 30000ms)
2023-11-05T11:26:40.773+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for config is config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.773+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.774+0530 I  SHARDING [Sharding-Fixed-0] Updating sharding state with confirmed set config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:40.774+0530 I  SHARDING [Sharding-Fixed-0] Updating ShardRegistry connection string for shard config from: config/172.25.122.151:27017 to: config/127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:41.191+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:41.191+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:41.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:41.691+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:41.779+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:42.191+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:42.191+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:42.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:42.691+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:42.782+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:43.191+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:43.191+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 5 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:43.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:43.691+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 6 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:44.191+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:44.191+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:44.191+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 7 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:44.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:44.691+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 8 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:45.192+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:45.192+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 9 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:45.691+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:45.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:45.691+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 10 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:46.191+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:46.191+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set config. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 11 checks in a row.
2023-11-05T11:26:46.691+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
2023-11-05T11:26:46.783+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017
2023-11-05T11:26:47.192+0530 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set config
^C2023-11-05T11:26:47.284+0530 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2023-11-05T11:26:47.284+0530 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close all sockets...
2023-11-05T11:26:47.285+0530 I  ASIO     [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:26:47.285+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Dropping all pooled connections to 172.25.122.151:27017 due to ShutdownInProgress: Shutting down the connection pool
2023-11-05T11:26:47.286+0530 I  SHARDING [shard-registry-reload] Periodic reload of shard registry failed  :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: could not get updated shard list from config server :: caused by :: interrupted at shutdown; will retry after 30s
2023-11-05T11:26:47.287+0530 W  SHARDING [mongosMain] Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: interrupted at shutdown
2023-11-05T11:26:47.287+0530 W  SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: InterruptedAtShutdown: interrupted at shutdown
2023-11-05T11:26:47.287+0530 I  ASIO     [ShardRegistry] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:26:47.287+0530 I  ASIO     [TaskExecutorPool-0] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:26:47.288+0530 W  SHARDING [signalProcessingThread] error encountered while cleaning up distributed ping entry for localhost.localdomain:27017:1699163800:3189634207339164914 :: caused by :: ShutdownInProgress: Server is shutting down
2023-11-05T11:26:47.288+0530 W  SHARDING [shard-registry-reload] cant reload ShardRegistry  :: caused by :: CallbackCanceled: Callback canceled
2023-11-05T11:26:47.288+0530 I  ASIO     [shard-registry-reload] Killing all outstanding egress activity.
2023-11-05T11:26:47.288+0530 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
````

Comment: Why do run an old version 4.2 which is End-of-Life?

Comment: You write, you created a config file `Mongod.conf` (please show us the file) but you start the `mongos` without specifying any config file, i.e. it is not use. Did you follow [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)?